# QGIS Difference: Could not add feature with geometry type MultiLineStringZ to layer of type MultiPolygonZ

Tags: pyqgis

I tried to take the Difference between two polygons, and I get an error:

my script is this :

```
from qgis import processing
from qgis.core import QgsField, QgsProject, QgsWkbTypes, QgsFeature
from datetime import datetime, timedelta



P3_boundary = r'C:\Users\CMCA\OneDrive - Boskalis\Documents\06 Boundaries and Plans\01 Map Boundaries\PhaseRev3_BoundariesOutside_v2.gpkg'

path_file = r'C:/Users/CMCA/Downloads'

date = datetime.strftime(datetime.now() - timedelta(1), "%Y%m%d")  # or "%Y%m%d_%H%M%S"

inlay = f'{path_file}/{date}/CDC+HEIC_2ndFill-{date}.gpkg'
print(f'input layer: {inlay}')


overlay = f'{path_file}/{date}/CDC+HEIC_1stFill-{date}.gpkg'
print(f'overlay layer: {overlay}')



Difference = processing.runAndLoadResults("native:difference", 
    {'INPUT': inlay,
    'OVERLAY': overlay,
    'OUTPUT': 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT',
    'GRID_SIZE': None

})





print("Dissolving...")



dissolved = processing.run("native:dissolve", 
    {'INPUT': Difference['OUTPUT'],
    'FIELD': [],
    'OUTPUT': 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'

})


print("union...")



union = processing.run("qgis:union", 
    {'INPUT': P3_boundary,
    'OVERLAY': dissolved['OUTPUT'],
    'OUTPUT': 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT',
    'OVERLAY_FIELDS_PREFIX': ''



})







print("clipping")



clip = processing.run("native:clip", 
    {'INPUT': union['OUTPUT'],
    'OVERLAY': dissolved['OUTPUT'],
    'OUTPUT': 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'
})["OUTPUT"]







QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(clip)
provider = clip.dataProvider()
field = QgsField("area3", QVariant.Double)
provider.addAttributes([field])
clip.updateFields()
index = provider.fieldNameIndex('area3')







for feat in clip.getFeatures():
    provider.changeAttributeValues({feat.id(): {index: feat.geometry().area()}})



    



print("Area Added....")







dont_delete = ["PhaseName", "area3", "otherfield"]
all_fields = clip.fields().names()
field_ids = [clip.fields().indexFromName(f) for f in all_fields if f not in dont_delete]
clip.dataProvider().deleteAttributes(field_ids)
clip.updateFields()







print("Finish Polygon...")







archive = f'{path_file}/CDC+HEIC_Difference-{date}.gpkg'

processing.runAndLoadResults("native:savefeatures", 
    {'INPUT': clip,
    'OUTPUT': archive,
    'LAYER_NAME': '',
    'DATASOURCE_OPTIONS': '',
    'LAYER_OPTIONS': '',
    'Add_save_file_to_map': True
 
})

print("Check your downloads folder..")
```

Error:
input layer: C:/Users/CMCA/Downloads/20240305/CDC+HEIC_2ndFill-20240305.gpkg
overlay layer: C:/Users/CMCA/Downloads/20240305/CDC+HEIC_1stFill-20240305.gpkg
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS33~1.2\apps\Python39\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
exec(code, self.locals)
File "", line 1, in 
File "", line 24, in 
File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS33~1.2/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\tools\general.py", line 149, in runAndLoadResults
return Processing.runAlgorithm(alg, parameters=parameters, onFinish=handleAlgorithmResults, feedback=feedback,
File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS33~1.2/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\core\Processing.py", line 176, in runAlgorithm
ret, results = execute(alg, parameters, context, feedback, catch_exceptions=False)
File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS33~1.2/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\gui\AlgorithmExecutor.py", line 70, in execute
results, ok = alg.run(parameters, context, feedback, {}, False)

then I tried doing it manually :

```
QGIS version: 3.32.2-Lima QGIS code revision: c0b8833964 Qt version:
5.15.3 Python version: 3.9.5 GDAL version: 3.7.1 GEOS version: 3.12.0-CAPI-1.18.0 PROJ version: Rel. 9.2.1, June 1st, 2023 PDAL version: 2.5.5 (git-version: f1a9ac) Algorithm started at: 2024-03-06T13:55:23 Algorithm 'Difference' starting… Input parameters: { 'GRID_SIZE' : None, 'INPUT' : 'C:/Users/CMCA/Downloads/20240305/CDC+HEIC_2ndFill-20240305.gpkg|layername=CDC+HEIC_2ndFill-20240305', 'OUTPUT' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'OVERLAY' : 'C:/Users/CMCA/Downloads/20240305/CDC+HEIC_1stFill-20240305.gpkg|layername=CDC+HEIC_1stFill-20240305' }

Creating spatial index Calculating difference Feature could not be written to Difference_af530894_4283_4a65_8199_1258dea1a6e0: Could not add feature with geometry type MultiLineStringZ to layer of type MultiPolygonZ Could not write feature Execution failed after 0.56 seconds

Loading resulting layers Algorithm 'Difference' finished`enter code here`
```

[image]

I still get the error , Is there any other way I can export my inlay and overlay layers so I will not encounter this error during union and

Comment: A very annoying error.. Try changing/modifying the geometries very slighty. You can [Snap to grid](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgissnappointstogrid), [Buffer](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgisbuffer) with a small distance, like a few centimeters or [Simplify](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgissimplifygeometries) then Union.

Comment: Thank you for your response , but do you know what causes this ?

Comment: Not for sure. I think the tool is creating some output geometry that isnt a polygon. For example if two polygons that overlay are almost identical except along the border, so the output is so narrow it is interpreted as a line which it is trying to write to the output polygon layer

Comment: thank you for the information